# How to group many rows into one row by Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, grouping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

I have 2 table like this
**Class table :**
[image]

And **Student Table:**
[image]

I want to join two table but i want to have result like this
ClsName StdName
A              George
B              Jenifer,Anjel,Alex
C              Alex,Joe,Michael

**how could achieve to this?**
in fact for each class i want to have one row with distinct their student name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
select c.name ClassName,
    STUFF(( SELECT  distinct ', ' + s.name
            FROM    student s
            WHERE   c.id = s.classid
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '')  Names
from class c
```

Result:

```
ClassName | Names
A         | George
B         | Alex, Anjel, Jenifer
C         | Alex, Joe, Micheal
```

Here is the working query that I used:

```
;with class(id, name) as
(
    select 1, 'A'
    union all
    select 2, 'B'
    union all
    select 3, 'C'
),
student(id, name, classid) as
(
    select 1, 'Alex', 3
    union all
    select 2, 'Alex', 3
    union all
    select 3, 'Alex', 3
    union all
    select 4, 'Joe', 3
    union all
    select 5, 'Micheal', 3
    union all
    select 6, 'Jenifer', 2
    union all
    select 7, 'Anjel', 2
    union all
    select 8, 'Alex', 2
    union all
    select 9, 'George', 1
)
select c.name,
    STUFF(( SELECT  distinct ', ' + s.name
            FROM    student s
            WHERE   c.id = s.classid
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '') Names
from class c
```

Comment: +1 Here's the evidence ;) http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dcbb2/6/0

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for that. I forgot sql fiddle had 2012, the 2008 wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT 
    distinct
    S.Classid,
    (
        SELECT name + ','
        FROM Student S2
        WHERE S2.Classid = S.Classid
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) StdName,
    C.name ClsName
FROM 
Student S INNER JOIN Class C
ON S.Classid = C.id
```

Comment: You may want to make it `','+name` and then [`STUFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) that to remove the first character, so that it doesn't end with a comma.